# Abp on v6.0.1 ,use openiddict '/connect/token' get token,and this token is not valid

Tags: abp

i create template porject use abp cli on v6.0.1,this project use defalut openiddict,
and i use apifox request '/connect/token' to get token,yes i get the token
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNh39.png)

i put in by request header
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIoP6.png)

and i got 401,this is response header
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkYl5.png)

what happen,an i doing it wrong?

i want to get the access_token ,to use my vue project request abp,but this token is not valid

Comment: There are few enough details for me to be able to help, and I haven't worked on OpenIddict to be specific on my answer. However the 401 error reminds me of the `AuthorizedAttribute` attribute. You must also be sure to have the modules and configuration for `Identity`, `Account` and `Permissions` (client and server).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `username` and `password` you also need to set `scope` parameter with your project name, then it'll work.